# How to make linux terminal refresh framebuffer

Tags: linux, terminal, framebuffer

I have written a small app that draws directly on /dev/fb0. I run it in a console-only environment without X-server. The problem I have is that once the app exits, the framebuffer stays the way it left it. Is it possible to make the terminal redraw all it's contents to refresh the screen after the app exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do(if it does not depend on design and conceptual requirements) is to issue execve(clear).
Perhaps even execve(reset) would help. But for the latter i do not guarantee. First will surely do the job.